# Binary file in C by input string

Tags: c

In MAIN we ask the user to type a string. Once the string has been taken, the character "/ N" should be removed.
Which added him as a last line before the sentry.
Use fgets - of the string if n. In such a way that the string is written including '/ 0'. At the end of which the program will write the string to a binary file.
Each character that we read from the file must be placed in a dynamic array, so that each fread element. Then, read the whole file with the dynamic array will be another character from the file. (Including '/ 0'.)

I don't know how to make "Each character that we read from the file must be placed in a dynamic array, so that each fread element."

```
int main() {
    char str[LEN];
    printf("\n Please enter the string: ");
    clean();
    fgets(str, LEN, stdin);
    removeNewLine(str);

    FILE *fp = fopen("1.dat", "w+b");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not open the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(fwrite(str, sizeof(str), 1, fp) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not write the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    rewind(fp);

    char tmp;
    while(fread(&tmp, sizeof(char), 1, fp) == 1)
        printf("%d, ", tmp);
    if(ferror(fp)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not read the file\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The easy way to do it is declare an array with automatic storage, (say `char buf[1024];`) then use `fread` to read into the buffer and with the `size` parameter as `1` it will return the number of characters placed in `buf`. Simply allocate/reallocate that number of characters after each `fread` and add that to the end of your dynamically allocated storage. Do that in a loop until `fread` returns less than `1024` (or `0`) which will indicate `EOF`.

Comment: You write characters to the file, and then read integers. `char` and `int` are two very different types. Most notable I doubt you ever come across a system where `sizeof(char)` is equal to `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: I fix the type from char to int but I don't know how allocate every char we read from file in dynamic array. @Some programmer dude

Comment: Do you know about the [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function? How about the other [related dynamic memory handling functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory)? Perhaps you should consider refresh the chapters in your text-book about dynamic memory handling?

Comment: I use malloc and do loop inside the fread function ?@Some programmer dude